# Adding data to an array and accessing the data inside the array outside the function Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, readline

I'm new to Javascript and I'm not understanding how to persist data in an array. In my function I'm reading a file line by line and saving it in an array. I figured that because the array is declared outside the function that data would remain in it, but that's not what happens. I would like to understand how to do when printing the values ​​of the array outside the function that data still remain.

My code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
  
var array = [];


async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('data.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    
      array.push(line);
    }
 

  //console.log(array.toString());
}

processLineByLine();
console.log(array.toString());
```

The expected output would be to have the data inside the array:

```
288355555123888,335333555584333,223343555124001,002111555874555,111188555654777,111333555123333
```

Comment: I made a mistake here, but my code is correct. I can print inside the function, but outside the function array is empty

Comment: @jsN00b it wont work, call is not in async block

Comment: @robert You can check my answer it explains the problem!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You wont get since it's async call. try below snippet

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

var array = [];

async function processLineByLine() {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('data.txt');
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity,
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {  
        array.push(line);
    }
}

processLineByLine().then(()=>{
    console.log(array);
});
```

if each line of data.txt is like 288355555123888, 335333555584333, 223343555124001,... and want to extract those numbers spit each line and then add it to array.

```
for await (const line of rl) {  
    array=[...array, ...line.split(',')];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I still understand basic Javascript concepts

Answer (score 1):

Because `processLineByLine` is an async function the `console.log` runs before the async has populated the array.

You need to log after the async function has completed, as shown below:

```
processLineByLine().then(() => console.log(array.toString()));
```

Also, you don't need to declare the `array` outside the function, you can move it inside the function and return it from there and that would passed as an argument to the `.then` callback, as shown below:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");

async function processLineByLine() {
  const array = [];
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("data.txt");

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    array.push(line);
  }

  return array;
}

processLineByLine().then((array) => console.log(array.toString()));
```